# <div> tab value is not available in $document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jqgrid

I have a cshtml mvc5 & razor 4 page.
In the page is a jqWidget grid.
The grid is populated on $(document).ready()
also on the page is a  populated by @HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"].ToString()

I'm finding the value of the  is not yet available for the $(document).ready() function executes.

How can I get a value from @HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"].ToString() (or some other means) into $(document).ready() so I can use the value when the jqgrid is being built?

Comment: is your session filled before you load view ?

Comment: The Controller ActionResult() set the Session[] before before ding a "return Redirect(url);  So I think that is a yes because the url is the call to the view.    However javascript "<%=Session[]...%> never evaluates to the value of the session variable.

Comment: The only thing I can get out of javascript "<%=Session[]...%>" is the string literal "<%=Session[]...%>"

Comment: can you post some code ? it will get value in document ready if session is set

Comment: where you using @HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"] in code ???

Comment: Post the html and controller relevant code.

Comment: @HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"].ToString() is razor.  It is in the cshtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if using jquery inside CSHTML then

```
  @section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {                
            alert('@HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"]');
          });
       }
    </script>
}
```

or else you can just set session in some hiddenfield and retrive in your jquery

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnUserId" data-value='@HttpContext.Session["userId"]' />
```

and retrive

```
var userId= $("#hdnUserId").data('value');
```

Comment: This is my @section{}  @section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/_ERPIndexjqxCustomersList.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

Comment: Thanks.  I'm scratching my head about this a little. I thought <div> & <input> are the same in terms of the life of a page and in respect to running js.  So I'm not clear why <input> worked & <div> didn't.  In fact, that thought right there is why I stopped myself from trying <input> and post this question.